# Visual Studio Built Nant.exe exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nant

I have the following line in the pre-build event:

```
"$(SolutionDir)SolutionItems\NAnt\bin\NAnt.exe" configMerge -D:buildfile="$(SolutionDir)SolutionItems\NAnt\default.build" -D:sourcefile="$(SolutionDir)Web\web.format.config" -D:destinationfile="$(SolutionDir)Web\web.config"
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error   191 The command ""D:\Projects\trunk\SolutionItems\NAnt\bin\NAnt.exe" configMerge -D:buildfile="D:\Projects\trunk\SolutionItems\NAnt\default.build" -D:sourcefile="D:\Projects\trunk\Web\web.format.config" -D:destinationfile="D:\Projects\trunk\Web\web.config"" exited with code 1.
```

Any idea why it says code 1? I also tried it without the parameters, that doesn't work either. Does Nant.exe work anyway with the pre-build event?

I know there are more questions like this. But none of them gave me an answer to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Code 1 means the nant build failed. Look closely at the output to see if something tells you *why* the build failed.